# VirtualBox debian 64. Can't restart my VM after install git ( but if someone know how make a dual boot on 2 drive I take it )

Tags: git, debian, virtualbox, multiboot

**Hi all,**
everything is in the title.

1. I create my VM debian x64
2. I Install git with "apt install git-all"

and after this steps I can't shutdown my VM with the interface ( I can close the VM with the cross of the windows and click on "shut down" )
but when I tried to launch this VM again the initialization failed and I don't have graphic interface anymore.

***Other option to help me :)***

I use VM cause I wan't to keep my window but I need debian.
I don't know how make a dual boot on 2 drive.

I mean I have windows on SSD (only the OS, the desktop and other files has store on my hdd ).
And I want to split my hdd in two part to put debian on one of then but I don't really know how do that.

**Hope someone gonna help me,
Have a good one. :)**

Answer (score 0):

I just use "sudo apt install git" and that solve the problem.

thanks to myself :D